# Statistics about music tourism

Tags: data-request

I'm a college student; for my thesis I need some statistics about international classical music tourism.

I need some data about how big international classical music tourism is in terms of spending and how much tourists' passion for music economically affects their behaviour when they travel.

Where/how can I find some useful data (hopefully free)?

Comment: Don't see any reason to down-vote this.

Comment: It's just very vague. I have no idea what data regarding _how much tourists' passion for music economically affects their behaviour when they travel_ would look like. I suppose data requests are within the scope of this site -- there is a tag, after all -- but, for me, this is just too vague to get a good answer here. I'll be proven wrong if a good answer is posted!

Comment: Could you please define - what is this "music tourism" ? // sidenote: i'm not sure any data for it exists, but you can try to salvage ticket concert purchases among non-citizens ...

Answer (score 1):

The European Commission produces reports on tourism as part of its Eurobarometer surveys, which you can find here: http://ec.europa.eu/public_opinion/index_en.htm. If you do a bit of searching you might find some useful data in these reports. For example, a report of European's attitudes towards tourism can be found here: http://ec.europa.eu/public_opinion/flash/fl_370_en.pdf. I know this is not exactly what you asked for, but there is usually reference to cultural tourism in these kinds of reports and from there you may get further breakdown in terms of music tourism. This, I cannot guaranteed, however.

A second place to look would be on the websites of national tourism offices (they usually have a publications section with reports and statistics) and also on websites of lobbying groups; for example, UK Music has a research section and there they cite numbers on economic impact of music tourism. See here: http://www.ukmusic.org/research/measuring-music-2015/.

Generally speaking, it's quite hard to come by good data for arts and tourism - except maybe in France. Hope my suggestions are helpful and best of luck.

(I made this an answer because it was too long for a comment).